# Yul/Inline Assembly: Revert with a custom error message

Tags: solidity, assembly, require, yul, revert

I am learning Yul for my Bachelor's thesis and I am currently stuck on understanding a small code segment with *require* and *revert* functions.

A simple require function in Solidity ...

```
require(_amountToRaise > 0, "Amount to raise smaller than 0");
```

... translates to Yul/Inline assembly with ...

```
if iszero(gt(_amountToRaise, 0)) {
    mstore(0x80, shl(229, 4594637))   // <--- what is this?
    mstore(0x84, 32)                  // <--- and this?
    mstore(0x104, 30)
    mstore(0x124, "Amount to raise smaller than 0")
    revert(0x80, 0x64)
}
```

EDIT: BE AWARE, as mentioned by the answers, that I have mixed up 0x... offsets. Correction in the two answers below.

I understand that the revert message, and strings as well, need to be encoded by specifying the byte-length (30) in the first 32 byte slot and the characters in the next 32 byte slot.
But what about the 4 byte (at 0x80) and 32 byte slot (at 0x84) after?
Is it some kind of hashed function signature I am not understanding?

The two lines are always the same with every require/revert function.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of code:

```
require(_amountToRaise > 0, "Amount to raise smaller than 0");
```

Produces revert with bytes equivalent to calldata of the following method:

```
function Error(string memory reason) external;
```

ABI-encoded calldata structure is the following:

```
4 bytes selector
32 bytes offset (value 0x20)
32 bytes string length
N bytes string, optionally padded to 32 bytes
```

So correct assembly generating this calldata (reason up to 32 bytes):

```
let ptr := mload(0x40) // Get free memory pointer
mstore(ptr, 0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000) // Selector for method Error(string)
mstore(add(ptr, 0x04), 0x20) // String offset
mstore(add(ptr, 0x24), 30) // Revert reason length
mstore(add(ptr, 0x44), "Amount to raise smaller than 0")
revert(ptr, 0x64) // Revert data length is 4 bytes for selector and 3 slots of 0x20 bytes
```

For the case of custom error types:

```
contract Foo {
    error MyError();
    error MyErrorWithValue(uint256);
    error MyErrorWithTwoValues(uint256, uint256);

    function f() external {
        revert MyError();
    }

    function g() external {
        revert MyErrorWithValue(555);
    }

    function h() external {
        revert MyErrorWithTwoValues(555, 666);
    }
}
```

Assembly equivalent:

```
function f() external {
    // revert MyError();
    bytes4 errorSelector = this.MyError.selector;
    assembly {
        mstore(0, errorSelector)
        revert(0, 4)
    }
}

function f() external {
    // revert MyErrorWithValue(555);
    bytes4 errorSelector = this.MyErrorWithValue.selector;
    assembly {
        mstore(0, errorSelector)
        mstore(4, 555)
        revert(0, 0x24)
    }
}

function h() external {
    // revert MyErrorWithValues(555, 666);
    bytes4 errorSelector = this.MyErrorWithTwoValues.selector;
    assembly {
        let ptr := mload(0x40)
        mstore(ptr, errorSelector)
        mstore(add(ptr, 0x04), 555)
        mstore(add(ptr, 0x24), 666)
        revert(ptr, 0x44)
    }
}
```

In the first two methods revert data fits in [scratch space (first 0x40 bytes)](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/internals/layout_in_memory.html#layout-in-memory), but third method doesn't fit and should use free memory pointer (stored in memory at 0x40). As some may think due to `revert` operation they could use beginning of the memory for storing more than 64 bytes - Solidity documentation states that this can't be considered as [memory-safe assembly](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/assembly.html?highlight=memory%20safe#memory-safety) if it's important in your case.

Using assembly with custom errors could produce issues with compiler generated ABI if this happens in `libraries`. Compiler 0.8.17 could not include custom error into ABI due non-detection of actual usage this error type. You can track this issue here: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/13149

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear and thorough answer, further examples and information at the end. It was a godsent! I think I was on the right path, as I thought it looked similar to the decoding of calldata when calling a function (with the 4 byte function signature and so on) but couldn't figure out that it was the decode Error(string). Thanks again!

Comment: @EyeEmmaJedi yes, encoding of revert is exactly the same as encoding function call.

Answer (score 3):

First I think you mixed some hexadecimal notation with some decimal ones, the correct decomposition should be :

```
if iszero(gt(_amountToRaise, 0)) {
    mstore(0x80, shl(229, 4594637)) 
    mstore(0x84, 32) 
    mstore(0xA4, 30)
    mstore(0xC4, "Amount to raise smaller than 0")
    revert(0x80, 0x64)
}
```

At a higher level this code is equivalent to :

```
require(_amountToRaise > 0, "Amount to raise smaller than 0");
```

Which is actually translated to :

```
if (amount <= 0) {
   revert("Amount to raise smaller than 0");
}
```

Where the `revert` returns an abi encoded custom error "call" for `Error(string)`.

The encoding can be decomposed that way :

```
 mstore(0x80, shl(229, 4594637))
```

Writes the function selection for [`Error(string)`](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=08c379a0) at [0x80, 0x84].

```
mstore(0x84, 32)
```

Writes the offset of the abi.encoded `string' at [0x84, 0xA4]with respect to the beginning of the encoded parameters (i.e., excluding the function selector), this is a normal behavior for abi.encoded dynamic parameters as you can see [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types).

```
mstore(0xA4, 30)
mstore(0xC4, "Amount to raise smaller than 0")
```

Respectively, write the length of the string and it's content.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer as well! I would have loved to mark both answers as a solution, but have gone ahead and marked the other one, as it contained some valuable background information. But I love your answer as well, as it is a quick fix and explanation :)